# What is the meaning of the coin symbol on my Nintendo 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

So on the home menu of my Nintendo 3DS, there is this coin symbol:

[image]

<sub>Sorry about the image being so large, I’m currently on mobile right now. I’ll fix it once I get access to a computer again</sub>
Now my question is: what does this symbol mean? I feel like it’s useful somehow, but I don’t know what it means. For context I haven’t played on my Nintendo 3DS for ~2 years (I’ve had it for ~7-7.5 years) so I don’t remember what this coin symbol represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [Play Coins](https://nintendo.fandom.com/wiki/Play_Coins)

> The player can obtain them by walking; players earn 1 coin for every 100 steps taken and can earn 10 coins daily, for a maximum of 300 in their bank at any given time. You can also get Play Coins by shaking your 3DS. Plus, if you change the date, you can get more than 10 Play Coins a day. The player can then use them to purchase applications and special content for their Nintendo 3DS.
>
> [image: Play coin icon]

The linked wiki provides a list of games that support the use of play coins, and their intended use